# Add new variable designator for setf?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, advising-functions

I think this is possible in Common Lisp (through overloading `setf`), but not sure about Emacs Lisp.

What I want to do would be something like:

```
(setf (local variable) value)
```

where the form `(local ...)` would call some code I've written and return the symbol to use for setting its value slot.

EDIT: From looking at gv.el it seems like advising `gv-get` would do the job, but maybe there's a better procedure for it?

EDIT2: Tried the suggestion from Stefan, close, but not good :(

```
(gv-define-setter local (value varname &optional buffer)
  `(with-current-buffer (or ,buffer (current-buffer))
     (setq ,varname ,value)))
```

which expands to:

```
(let* ((v bar))
 (with-current-buffer (or nil (current-buffer))
  (setq v 42)))
```

Obviously, not what I wanted. I was trying to do it with advising as mentioned above and with `gv-define-expander`, but there's just too much quoting going on, and I can't find a way to loose the `let` part of the expression with the redundant substitution.

EDIT3:

OK, unless I messed something seriously in the scope or the evaluation sequence of the value the variable will be set to, this seems to work:

```
(gv-define-expander local
  (lambda (do &rest args)
    (let ((varname (first args))
          (buffer (or (second args) '(current-buffer)))
          (value (funcall do nil #'identity)))
      `(with-current-buffer ,buffer
         (setq ,varname ,value)))))
```

Comment: BTW, rather than `local`, I'd call it `buffer-local-value` ;-)

Comment: Then add a (defmacro local (var buffer) `(buffer-local-value ',var ,buffer)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `gv-define-expander`, `gv-define-setter`, and `gv-define-simple-setter` (in order of growing simplicity of use).

You might want to try the 100% guaranteed untested code (note how I pass the `with-current-buffer+setq` to `do` rather than calling `do` with dummy arguments, so that this things has a chance to work when used with `push`).

```
(gv-define-expander local
  (lambda (do &rest varname &optional buffer)
    (macroexp-let2 nil b buffer
      (funcall do `(buffer-local-value ',varname ,b)
               (lambda (value)
                `(with-current-buffer ,b
                   (setq ,varname ,value)))))))
```

Comment: `gv-define-setter` can only be used for places that "behave like functions" (i.e. the arg to your `local` will be evaluated), so you'd have to use `set` instead of `setq` and `(local 'var)` instead of `(local var)`.  Otherwise, use `gv-define-expander` which is more complex.

Comment: There are a few examples of `gv-define-expander` in Emacs's own source code (grep for `(gv-expander` and `(gv-define-expander`).

Comment: No, the first argument of `do` is not ignored in general, tho in the case of `setf` it is indeed ignored.  But if you try `(push foo (local bar))` this argument will definitely be used.

Comment: No, the `macroexp-let2` is more like `(let ((b buffer)) ...` just making sure that `buffer' is executed only once and is bound to a variable that will not conflict with some other variable nearby.